# Compile elixir permission denied

Tags: elixir

When I want to compile my project on windows, I've got compiler permission denied:

```
D:\Elixir\issues>iex -S mix
Eshell V7.2.1  (abort with ^G)
Compiled lib/issues.ex
Compiled lib/issues/github_issues.ex
Compiled lib/issues/cli.ex
** (EXIT from #PID<0.56.0>) an exception was raised:
    ** (File.Error) could not open d:/Elixir/issues/_build/dev/lib/issues/.compile.elixir: permission denied
        (elixir) lib/file.ex:1061: File.open!/3
        (mix) lib/mix/compilers/elixir.ex:246: Mix.Compilers.Elixir.write_manifest/2
        (mix) lib/mix/compilers/elixir.ex:112: anonymous fn/2 in Mix.Compilers.Elixir.compile_manifest/5
        (elixir) lib/agent/server.ex:31: Agent.Server.handle_cast/2
        (stdlib) gen_server.erl:615: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
        (stdlib) gen_server.erl:681: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For anyone else who might see this question, the first thing you should have done was to try to write a file to the d:/Elixir/issues/_build/dev/lib/issues directory.  This has almost nothing to do with Elixir--it's the user's permissions to that directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the user does not have permissions to `_build/dev` directory. It happens when you run the build as an administrator first and then try run it as a regular user. Regular user can't overwrite files created by administrator and you get an error.

Try to add permissions for your user. For example using [cacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx) or even from GUI http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7